# how do I get the network connection window to stop popping up?

Tags: network, internet

This window pops up every few minutes (macbook pro circa 2006 running OS 10.6)

[image: network connection window]

I no longer have this internet service, so how do I get it to go away? Hitting cancel or ok just makes it pop back up in a few minutes. Doesn't matter if the airport is turned on or off - it still comes up.

Thanks!
Kendra

Comment: Please take a screenshot of your Network settings in System Preferences, and a screenshot of AirPoirt Utility located in `/Applications/Utilities`

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you just need to delete one of the connections in Network Preferences.

Go to System Preferences > Network

You will likely have a list of connections on the left, Ethernet, Wi-Fi, etc. One of them is likely the connection above.

Click on each of them, in turn till you find the one that corresponds to the connection in your question. Click on the "-" at the bottom left to delete the selected connection.

That should do it. If not then we will need the screen captures "TheBro21" asked for.